# solve for t that minimizes/maximizes z(t) within an ellipsoidal cone

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

**Context:**
My current work involves ellipsoidal cones - the intersection of a cone and ellipsoid where the origin of each is at $(0,0,0)$ and where I say it is in 'canonical position' when the cone axis is the $(0,0,1)$ vector and the ellipsoid is rotated accordingly.

For visualization, the pictures[image][image] show two orientations of the same example where the ellipsoid radii are $(36.8, 23.2, 15.99)$, the elliptical cone's half angles are $(23.67, 52.8)$ degrees, and the cone's position within the ellipsoid is rotated as desired (I can provide exact details if needed). The triangle empirically approximates the $z$-maximizer point.

The red contour represents the $P(t)$ function for $360$ values of $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $P$ is the $z \ge 0$ intersection of the line through $f(t)$ on the ellipse and the ellipsoid itself in canonical ellipsoidal cone position.  $f(t)$ is the elliptic curve formed by the intersection of the plane $z=k$ with the cone, where for simplicity, $k=1$.  The points from $f(t)$ form the lines connected from the cone origin that I intersect with the ellipsoid.  The intersection of the line and the ellipsoid is done via the standard quadratic equation method described by Paul Bourke (http://www.paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/)
where of course $f(t)$ is first rotated into canonical (axis-aligned) ellipsoid position.

**Problem To Solve:**
I want to analytically compute $min/max$ $z(t)$ where $t$ is parameter $\in [0, 2*\pi]$ on the ellipse formed by intersecting the cone with the plane $z=k$.  For simplicity I use $k=1$.

The standard methodology for solving my problem analytically is to create an expression for $z(t)$, differentiate w.r.t. $t$, set to $0$, and solve for $t$.  Of course, I can solve this numerically through a 'line search' on $t$ but would like to do better.

**My Approach:**
Briefly, the Bourke's line-ellipsoid intersection method is this:

Find points $P (x,y,z)$ on a line defined by two points $P_1 (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2 (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ which is described by
$P = P_1 + \mu(P_2 - P_1)$ or in each coordinate
$x(\mu) = x_1 + \mu(x_2 - x_1)$,
$y(\mu) = y_1 + \mu(y_2 - y_1)$,and
$z(\mu) = z_1 + \mu(z_2 - z_1)$.

An axis-aligned ellipsoid centered at $P_3 (x_3,y_3,z_3)$ with radii $a$, $b$, and $c$ is described by

$(\frac{x - x_3}{a})^2 + (\frac{y - y_3}{b})^2 + (\frac{z - z_3}{c})^2 = 1^2$.

Substituting the equation of the line into the sphere gives a quadratic equation of the form

$A\mu^2 + B\mu + C = 0$

Because $P_1$ and $P_3$ are both $(0,0,0)$, this simplifies dramatically to

$A\mu^2 + C =0$ where

$A = [(bcx_2)^2 + (acy_2)^2 + (abz_2)^2]$ and

$C = -(abc)^2$.  I can provide the algebra if requested.

Now, note that $A$ is really $A(t)$ because $P_2$, the point on the cone's ellipse at $z=1$ is really $P_2(t)$.

$P_2(t) = [r_{x(1)}cos(t), r_{y(1)}sin(t), 1]$ where $z=1$ and $r_{x(1)}$ and $r_{y(1)}$ are the radii of the cone ellipse on the plane $z=1$.

Note that the positive/negative roots of the quadratic, $\mu$, are actually the $z(t)$-values I will need in my solution...so solving for $z(t)=\mu(t)$ would answer my question.

Finally, note that to put $P_2$ in axis-aligned ellipsoid space, apply a rotation matrix, $R*P_2$, and substitute this into $A(t)$.

Now we finally have a means of expressing the quadratic as a function of $t$.

Again, I can add the ugly algebra, but I end up with an equation $A(t)\mu^2 + C = 0$ or

$A(t)z(t)^2 + C = 0$

that will contain a collection of $cos^2(t)$, $sin^2(t)$, and $cos(t)sin(t)$ terms that I will then need to differentiate.
$A(t) = [(bc(R_{11}cos(t) + R_{12}sin(t) + R_{13}))^2 + (ac(R_{21}cos(t) + R_{22}sin(t) + R_{23}))^2 + (ab(R_{31}cos(t) + R_{32}sin(t) + R_{33}))^2]$

where the $R_{ij}$ values are the elements of the rotation matrix $R$ and

$z(t) = [R_{31}r_{x}cos(t) + R_{32}r_{y}sin(t) + R_{33}]$

**Question for the Community** Do I have the right approach? How do I get rid of the $cos(t)sin(t)$ terms in the derivative when solving for $t$? I can handle a derivative with $cos^2$ and $sin^2$ but not one with $cos(t)sin(t)$ terms.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $f(t)$?. Is your problem equivalent to determine the $\min\max z(t)$ in $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ where $g(\cdot)$ represents the intersection curve between the ellipsoidal cone and the ellipsoid?

Comment: Thank you - I edited to explicitly show $f(t)$.  Come to think of it, I think you are correct in that my problem is equivalent to what you describe.  This would imply inserting the equation of the rotated ellipsoid into the cone equation, going through the algebra, taking the derivative, etc.  Before I go off and try to solve that myself, any thoughts on if the method described here would be simpler to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this problem by using the Lagrange multiplier method.  Let the vector $k = [0,0,1]^T$, and let $ r = [x,y,z]^T $, then you cone and ellipsoid equations are

$ r^T Q_c r = 0 $ (for the cone), and

$r^T Q_e r = 1 $ (for the ellipsoid)

And you want to maximize $z = k^T r $, so define

$ G(r, \lambda_1, \lambda_2) = k^T r + \lambda_1( r^T Q_c r) + \lambda_2 ( r^T Q_e r - 1) $

Take the gradient of $G$ and set it to zero,

$ \nabla G = k + \lambda_1 (2 Q_c r) + \lambda_2 (2 Q_e r ) = \mathbf{0} $

Since vectors $i = [1,0,0]^T$ and $j = [0,1,0]^T$ satisfy $i^T k = 0 $ and $j^T k = 0 $ , then we now have two equations

$ i^T \nabla G = \lambda_1 (2 i^T Q_c r) + \lambda_2 (2 i^T Q_e r) = 0 $

$ j^T \nabla G = \lambda_1 (2 j^T Q_c r) + \lambda_2 (2 j^T Q_e r ) = 0 $

Since $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ cannot be zero, this implies that the determinant of this homogenous system of equations must be zero, i.e.

$ (2 i^T Q_c r) (2 j^T Q_e r) - (2 j^T Q_c r) (2 i^T Q_e r ) = 0 $

Simplifying and re-arraning, this becomes

$ r^T ( Q_c (i j^T - j i^T ) Q_e ) r = 0 $

Note that

$ i j^T - j i^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0  \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && 0  \\ -1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix} $

If we call this matrix $E$, then our three equations that we have to solve are

$r^T Q_c r = 0 \tag{1} $

$r^T Q_e r = 1 \tag{2} $

$r^T Q_c E Q_e r = 0 \tag{3} $

And these can be solved using [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/) or [Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

I've worked an example in [this Sage Worksheet](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9VNuO2jAQfUfiH0bbh9ipgSQsUtUqf9E3FFZRMGA1xKntZpN8fWecC7CLFhDxeOacOTOeuBWd6IUTNm1yw4J2MgO-XLSx6GLRx5DC4Bxt8h1loa55-WZ1mcI1d0a17IeALbrcpUVERIsOF7VifJOQ1U_W63JhKGbE7fexiESUiX0koNCWIQMXsLKq8stMAHkm8xaTZZjOdPdMg6vjIGCGdDyDgSLGXWJbTQ4fNWEy8Hz9Z77-JoeWJHWyYMKPDp-HUg3itEM204emDU3nbb-h3dqZvLK1tpJh3HJRVI8NIY6xJfEmmdf4Ww3UsnwAbHaH5BG0PTzAkOWQ3JAoIZRlSIJQ1j1VS0V09Nf78FOhK0mIe8lhUYUGfbIsP7mIFl00Nx67p8OFNMWROCW0iaBpD-Llook-ddyfuf1rHEt46Fvtd4bKVfHPNKSokYXTho0QPO4HAJ0BRn8DCyGMmFJJC7oCd5GAKhRKVkcfowHsIRnjDr_RC3Me1GjpsfEJgDXRx3qbiPuK7tXZcFguF2e01LUuVaHcW11qtz0yOOEZsxbEaid2qJV186ofhvd1mK1S0-kEpTpf3NlIWQUCcltj6W8md0qnOCz4pdRn-P4sUQKUaaSf87AeR2knYHeXJjDyGKCp6xwZ6MWK1ruJuM5NfpV4SsVMPRSI7G6QnIT0fnPh6dKgwxbrd9TrLqr4U0lLXdz6cZf3Rx5hATSoq9s9QE8_fE8nT04ztvXjNA8TThheSNR7XTaSMezxKRGnLXa1FdAJ6Pkvyn7CYhWoCpD2LFkpK4YIzn8uF4CfdmDYq2wfZeNWnLZrc7GMryt6YT-ExWNY93VYMob1T8JqoyrH8I59AXihi9Y_-5gUw_jB8i76nZ35f2Vkl_0=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).  It contains the plot of an ellipsoid and a cone, their intersection curve for $z \gt 0$, and the critical points which are solutions of $(1),(2),(3)$.

Comment: Hi and thank you.  Apologies for the delay in responding.  I have 2 follow-up questions: 1). The KKT approach requires I solve additional equations whereas my goal is an analytical closed-form solution...understood it may not be possible but that was the aim of my question.  I can use Alglib within my code to solve your equations, though, I believe .

Comment: 2). In your Sage worksheet, I can follow and verify the results working for different ellipsoid radii but as I add in different rotation matrices (since the ellipsoid, in general, is rotated around the cone, as described above), the answer fails...could you update your worksheet to add in a rotation matrix of the ellipsoid please?

Comment: @WilliamM.  I've added the modification that you requested and updated my answer.

Comment: Perhaps linking to the [Cloud](https://www.wolfram.com/cloud/) platform that offers free access would be a better option than MOnline?

Comment: Thanks @user170231 for that.  I didn't know about this option.